# Ошибка при повторном нажатии кнопки поиска элемента на странице

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

**Сценарий**

1. Заполняю:
   textBox34.Text;
   textBox19.Text;
   textBox1.Text;
2. Нажимаю кнопку
   Код выполняется
3. Нажимаю кнопку второй раз
   Выпадает ошибка:

> No frame element found with name or id ads_frame1

**Код**

```
Browser.SwitchTo().Frame(textBox34.Text); // переключаемся в фрейм  
IWebElement selector = Browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector(textBox19.Text));  
textBox1.Text = selector.Text;  
Application.DoEvents();  
selector.Click();
```

**Вопрос**
Почему при повторном нажатии кнопки выпадает ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего после первого "поиска" (прохода) у Вас перестраивается страничка и в результате фрейм исчезает.

Comment: @androschuk.После первого нажатия кнопки, код выполняется. Захожу в Хром проверяю наличие фрейма. В Хроме фрейм есть и не изменился. Нажимаю кнопку повторно - ошибка